# My relatively positioned divs arent reacting to each others borders

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have two divs not nested within each other

```
<div1> </div>


<div2>Hey! Text here </div>
```

div 1 is just a white box I have styled as..

```
position: relative;
color: #ffffff;
margin: 0px auto;
width: 1020px;
height: 400px;
background-color: #ffffff;
top: 100px;
```

and div 2 is styled as

```
font-size: 12px;
position: relative;
text-align: left;
color: #ffffff;
margin: auto;
top: 25px;
left: 25px;
```

my problem is, instead of the top of div2 starting from the bottom of div 1 its somewhere in the lower middle of div 1 and my text is directly behind it and cant be seen unless I change the top: of div2 to somewhere around 100px. Is there a reason its not positioning itself directly below div1? They both are positioned relatively and should be reacting to each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `margin-top: 100px;` instead of `top:100px;` at `div1`. It will do the job.

Example [***here***](http://cssdeck.com/labs/ht8ty7dz)

`top` is for tweak an element with use of `position` property. `margin-top` is for measuring the external distance to the element, in relation to the previous one. Hence when you use `top` your `div` overlaps on each other.

Comment: thank you, I messed with it and it seems to be working now. Though I removed top: and replaced it with margin-top: just to be safe.

Answer (score 1):

Check this remove top of div1

```
.div1{
    position: relative;
color: #000;
margin: 0px auto;
width: 1020px;
height: 400px;
background-color: #ffffff;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
```

check this link 
http://jsfiddle.net/nikkirs/7q1mk10k/9/

Answer (score 0):

Try remove the `top: 100px`, as this combined with a relative layout will move relative to 'itself' (where it would normally be positioned), and will not affect adjacent elements. [CSS-Tricks on positioning elements](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/) take on this

If your goal is to have block elements in a stacked position, you would be better of removing `position:relative;` and use [clearfix](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/) on the elements themselves